# how to filter out specific AWS rds instances which have specific tags using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, ansible, amazon-rds

I am trying to list all the AWS RDS instances which have my cusotm tag defined using ansible playbooks, I am using the rds_instance_info to get the data of all the rds instances.

```
    - name: List RDS instances
      hosts: localhost
      tasks:
        - name: Get RDS instance info
          amazon.aws.rds_instance_info:
            region: xx-xxxx-x
            aws_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            aws_secret_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          register: rds_info
    
        - set_fact:
            var: "{{ rds_info.instances | selectattr('tags', 'defined') | selectattr('tags.stack', 'equalto', 'custom-tag-value') | default([]) | list }}"
          loop: "{{ rds_info.instances }}"

        - debug:
            msg: "{{ item.db_instance_identifier }}"
          loop: "{{ var }}"
```

The error i get is,

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stack'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'stack'
```

Not all instances have tags defined and the ones having tags defined don't always have the tag "stack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"List all instances which have my custom tag defined."***

A: Use *json_query*. For example, given the data for testing

```yaml
    rds_info:
      instances:
        - name: A
          tags: {stack: custom-tag-name, tag: tag_A}
        - name: B
          tags: {tag: tag_B}
        - name: C
        - name: D
          tags: {stack: X, tag: tag_D}
```

Declare the list of *"instances which have my custom tag defined"*

```yaml
    result: "{{ rds_info.instances|json_query(result_query) }}"
    result_query: '[?tags.stack == `custom-tag-name`]'
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - name: A
    tags:
      stack: custom-tag-name
      tag: tag_A
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    # Not all instances have tags defined and the ones having tags defined
    # don't always have the tag 'stack'

    rds_info:
      instances:
        - name: A
          tags: {stack: custom-tag-name, tag: tag_A}
        - name: B
          tags: {tag: tag_B}
        - name: C
        - name: D
          tags: {stack: X, tag: tag_D}


    result: "{{ rds_info.instances|json_query(result_query) }}"
    result_query: '[?tags.stack == `custom-tag-name`]'

#    result: "{{ rds_info.instances|
#                selectattr('tags', 'defined')|
#                selectattr('tags.stack', 'equalto', 'custom-tag-name') }}"
#
#    result: 'VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: ''dict object'' has no attribute ''stack''

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
```